# where to store the jwt token retrieved from cognito

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using cognito in a react, redux application and currently I store the cooke in redux and in a cookie for when the user refreshes the page.

```
loginSuccess(result.accessToken.jwtToken)
```

I then add the cookie to each protected request as a header:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/getData/', {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
```

My problem is how to secure the token in the cookie from XSS attacks or man in the middle attacks, I would need to set the cookie as httponly.

I think cognito might store stuff in the localstorage by default and I would like to stop this.

Comment: absolutely love to know why this was down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you use Cognito's hosted UI or not. I have worked with it and it uses HTTPS only, secure cookies, and XSRF tokens to securely store session information. Even if you don't use the hosted UI and `use amazon-cognito-identity` SDK, it uses secure cookies to store tokens. See **Use Case 26** on [this page](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js).

And finally, if you do find that Cognito stores something an insecure storage (something which I have yet to see), you should report it to AWS support. I mean there isn't much we can do if something is wrong with their service (say the built-in UI).